# How to set variable in Tkinter OptionMenu?

Tags: python, tkinter

So my question is why the Tkinter `OptionMenu` is not setting to `4.5` as a default? Do I just have to put `4.5` at the beginning of the `avgdisc_thresh` list or am I doing something wrong?

```
avgdisc_thresh = [3.5, 4, 4.5, 5, 5.5, 6]

avgdisc_var = tk.StringVar()
avgdisc_var.set("4.5")

loss_option = ttk.OptionMenu(
    loss_top_win, avgdisc_var, *avgdisc_thresh)
loss_option.grid(
    row=0, column=0)
```

Thanks!

Comment: In line 6, is ttk a typo? Do you mean tk.OptionMenu...?

Comment: No. ttk has some more stylish menus, etc than tk. I use it wherever it works

Comment: Ahh. I see. they don't work together. had to use tk.. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the ttk `OptionMenu`, the first value after the name of the variable is used as the default, which overrides whatever value you had previously set. The simple solution is to provide the default value when creating the widget.

Example:

```
loss_option = ttk.OptionMenu(loss_top_win, avgdisc_var, "4.5", *avgdisc_thresh)
```

Comment: So either I use `tk` or change the format of my parameters? I had not realized `ttk` had a separate syntax

Comment: I am trying to figure out why they would do this - it seems redundant to set a variable and then have the variable changed by the default value. Maybe you could help me understand?

Comment: @6seven8: not really. The Tkinter `OptionMenu` also takes the default value as the first parameter. In `Tkinter` it's a positional parameter, in ttk it's a keyword parameter.